# How to used aweber api to add new subscriber usign php and aweber OAuth 2.0 Examples

Tags: php, aweber

i am used aweber api in add subscriber and OAuth 2.0 Examples usign php

```
require_once('aweber_api/aweber_api.php');
$body = [
  'ad_tracking' => 'ebook',
  'custom_fields' => [
    'apple' => 'fuji',
    'pear' => 'bosc'
  ],
  'email' => 'anand@gmail.com',
  'ip_address' => '192.168.1.1',
  'last_followup_message_number_sent' => 0,
  'misc_notes' => 'string',
  'name' => 'Anand',
  'strict_custom_fields' => 'true',
  'tags' => [
    'slow',
    'fast',
    'lightspeed'
  ]
];
$headers = [
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
    'Accept' => 'application/json',
    'User-Agent' => 'AWeber-PHP-code-sample/1.0'
];
$listId='myid';
$accountId='myid';
$url = "https://api.aweber.com/1.0/accounts/{$accountId}/lists/{$listId}/subscribers";
$response = $client->post($url, ['json' => $body, 'headers' => $headers]);
echo $response->getHeader('Location')[0];
```

Error Code :

Notice: Undefined variable: client in D:\xampp\htdocs\Aweber\index.php on line 30

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function post() on null in D:\xampp\htdocs\Aweber\index.php:30 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\Aweber\index.php on line 30

Comment: where do you think `$client` is defined?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined)

Comment: not work and this is get post method....

Comment: `$client` simply is not defined in your code... that's all we can possibly say

Answer (score 1):

The AWeber examples make use of a third party HTTP client for PHP called Guzzle. You need to set up the client first before you'll be able to use it. You can see an example of this in the code examples on AWeber's GitHub here:

https://github.com/aweber/public-api-examples/blob/ea87b1f504cb97d9081a9ea9c8737ae9fd8838e3/php/manage-subscriber

Note the call to create the client:

```
// Create a Guzzle client
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
```

Documentation for Guzzle can be found here:

http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/

It also looks like you're missing the authorization header. When you make the API call it will fail unless you include your access token in the header, so don't forget that part! You can add it to your existing headers like so:

```
$headers = [
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
    'Accept' => 'application/json',
    'User-Agent' => 'AWeber-PHP-code-sample/1.0',
    'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $accessToken
];
```

Where $accessToken is a variable you initialize with your token somewhere.